# Unable to pull the image to run a pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Image of Pod Detail
[image]
Failed to pull image
The image has been pushed in the azure registry through docker for windows.
image name provided: as provided during tag through docker

Answer (score 0):

You currently provided very little detail.

Is your kubernetes cluster correctly configured to pull images from azure registry ? As far as I can see it isn't. Is this a managed AKS k8s cluster? If not, by default won't be able to access your private azure registry and will need to be configured with the credentials needed to access your private azure registry.

http://docs.heptio.com/content/private-registries/pr-docker-hub.html

Another possibility is you're pushing a Windows-based container onto linux based worker nodes which can only run linux based containers.

Comment: The cluster is managed AKS k8s cluster and the image can be successfully pulled on local. How can I verify that the kubernetes cluster is correctly configured to pull images

Comment: Is this the only deployment having issues or do all deployments fail to pull? You may want to try deploying a simple hello-world application.

What is the base image for your container? I ask because you may be pushing Windows container into Linux node.

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience with GKE but if you want to pull docker images from a repository that is not in the same project as the GKE cluster, you have to provide credentials for the image to be pulled.

I do this with a secret in Kubernetes that contains a .dockerconfig.json:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: <REDACTED>
```

In order to create a secret of this type i've used a template as such:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <SECRET_NAME> \
  --docker-server=https://gcr.io \
  --docker-username=_json_key \
  --docker-email=<SVC_ACCOUNT_EMAIL> \
  --docker-password=<CONTENTS_OF_SVC_ACCOUNT_CREDS_FILE>
```

Once thats created you will need to mount to secret to the relevant pods / deployment. In the pod spec you will need:

```
imagePullSecrets:
      - name: <SECRET_NAME>
```

(its a list because you can mount many secrets to pull from other places)

I imagine that azure has a similar setup whereby any images in the same project as the cluster will be able to be pulled. But any images hosted in another azure project or external image repo will need credentials.
I use the setup described to also pull google container registry images to a local minikube.

So I think we need to work out where your docker image is hosted and if credentials are needed to pull that image.

Comment: The images and the cluster both are in the same registry.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess that you've already tried the minimal options given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#unable-to-pull-image